# problema na hora de imprimir na tela o conteúdo de uma classe que esta armazenada em uma mutableList com no Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Esse é o código

```
enum class Nivel { BASICO, INTERMEDIARIO, DIFICIL }



data class ConteudoEducacional(var nome: String, val duracao: Int = 60)

data class Formacao(val nome: String, var dificuldade: Any, var conteudos: List<ConteudoEducacional>) {
  
 var selecionar = when(dificuldade){
    
        1 -> dificuldade =  Nivel.BASICO; 
        2  ->  dificuldade = Nivel.INTERMEDIARIO; 
        3 -> dificuldade =  Nivel.DIFICIL;
    else -> println("numero inválido")
    
}

    val inscritos = mutableListOf<Usuario>()
    
    fun matricular(usuario: Usuario) {
 
        inscritos.add(usuario)
    }
}

class Usuario(var nome: String, var idade: Int)

fun main() {
    var user1 = Usuario("Valentin", 18)
    var POO= ConteudoEducacional("POO") 
    val List = ConteudoEducacional("List", 120)
    val conteudo = mutableListOf<ConteudoEducacional>(POO, List)
    val Formacao1 = Formacao("JAVA e Kotlin", 1, conteudo)
    println(Formacao1.toString())
    Formacao1.matricular(user1)
    println(Formacao1.inscritos)

 
}
```

Essa é a saída

```
Formacao(nome=JAVA e Kotlin, dificuldade=BASICO, conteudos=[ConteudoEducacional(nome=POO, duracao=60), ConteudoEducacional(nome=List, duracao=120)])
[Usuario@3eb07fd3]
```

Eu gostaria de invés de printar isso [Usuario@3eb07fd3] ele printa-se as informações armazenadas como o nome do usuário cadastrado

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer printar os dados do usuário, da mesma forma que fez com a `Formacao` basta que voce altere sua classe para uma `data class`, que dessa forma terá algumas extensões a mais, como a `toString` que você precisa.

Exemplo

```
data class Usuario(var nome: String, var idade: Int)
```

Caso queira mudar a formatação ao printar, ai você precisa sobreescrever o método `toString` das suas *data classes*, da seguinte forma:

```
data class Usuario(var nome: String, var idade: Int) {
  override fun toString() : String {
    return "Dados do usuário -> Nome: $nome, idade: $idade"
  }
}
```

#### Exemplo funcional

```
data class Usuario(var nome: String, var idade: Int) {
  override fun toString() : String {
    return "Dados do usuário -> Nome: $nome, idade: $idade"
  }
}
  
fun main() {
    val user = Usuario(nome = "Matheus", idade = 10)
    print(user.toString())
}
```

> Você pode testar online no [Kotlin
> playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/).